# Flask app does not talk to included files

Tags: nginx, flask, python-3.4, uwsgi

I am following the tutorial [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/).

My nginx File:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @application;
    }
    location @application {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

The terminal thing - after activating the virtualenv:

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock --module runserver --callable app --enable-threads --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

cat runserver.py

```
from __init__ import app

import routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.secret_key = "BuckyCaptainAmericaHydraStarkTonyWidowBlack"
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

cat routes.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request, session, redirect, url_for, flash, make_response
import datetime
import json
from bson.json_util import dumps
from controller import actionController
from controller import dataController
from controller import usersController
from controller import authController
import base64
from flask.ext.paginate import Pagination
from __init__ import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```

This works perfect!

but, instead of Hello World.. If do the regular thing.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
        if 'loggedin' in session:
                authController.Auth.forward()
```

It throws Internal Server Error.

When I remove the configuration and just perform:

```
python3 runserver.py
```

**It has NO PROBLEM at all and works amazing when started via shell!**

So, if I call the included files (via import), and use uwsgi they stop working.

Comment: Sorry, explain please.... How can I correct this?

Comment: Maybe write an answer..?

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or the actual error (including the full traceback), it was just a guess. I created a local application with as much of your working code as I could and I wasn't able recreate the problem. It looks like my guess was wrong.

Comment: Oh wait... Make it an answer... You are da real MVP!!!! Thank you @dirn Can't wait to tick your answer! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask uses the secret key to sign the session cookie. You assign it a value like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # snip
    app.secret_key = "BuckyCaptainAmericaHydraStarkTonyWidowBlack"
    # snip
```

This block only runs when you execute `runserver.py` directly. That's why

```
$ python3 runserver.py
```

works. When you run your application through uWSGI, however, the check evaluates to false and the secret key is never set.

To fix this, move `app.secret_key = ...` outside the if block. Better yet, move it to `__init__.py` where you instantiate `app`. This way your app will always have its secret key.

Comment: that was `__init__`